# Is there a way to track the progress of a "docker pull"?

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to monitor the progress of `docker pull` remotely. Here's what my normal `docker pull` looks like:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from <docker image>
10175de2f0c4: Already exists
bb03ecf58e18: Downloading [===>                                               ]  63.79MB/1.04GB
87a8c4578c5a: Download complete
edf0a928172b: Downloading [===>                                               ]   45.4MB/710.1MB
56c25f9d90d4: Waiting
27d4409f004f: Waiting
e82924e59638: Waiting
```

I figured I'd end up needing to do some level of scripting in order to get an overall % output that I'm looking for. However, when I try to `tee` the output above into a text file, it suddenly no longer shows the progress bars or the amount downloaded vs the full size (e.g. 1MB/50MB).

Tee'ing changes the output to this:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from <docker image>
10175de2f0c4: Already exists
bb03ecf58e18: Pulling fs layer
87a8c4578c5a: Pulling fs layer
edf0a928172b: Pulling fs layer
56c25f9d90d4: Pulling fs layer
27d4409f004f: Pulling fs layer
e82924e59638: Pulling fs layer
27d4409f004f: Waiting
56c25f9d90d4: Waiting
e82924e59638: Waiting
87a8c4578c5a: Verifying Checksum
87a8c4578c5a: Download complete
56c25f9d90d4: Verifying Checksum
56c25f9d90d4: Download complete
27d4409f004f: Verifying Checksum
27d4409f004f: Download complete
e82924e59638: Verifying Checksum
e82924e59638: Download complete
edf0a928172b: Verifying Checksum
edf0a928172b: Download complete
```

It looks exactly the same in the text file that I tee'd the output to. The size of the layer is no longer displayed.

Is there a way to somehow get a % of the overall docker pull progress, or at least a way to be able to stream this progress into a text file so that everything shows?

Comment: try redirecting stderr to stdout before you pipe it. `docker pull myimage 2>&1 | tee`. Although this will write alot of text, if you make it work. Not sure if you really want that.

Comment: Tried that too unfortunately, but the size of the layers and the progress bars aren't being displayed still.

Answer (score 3):

This may be crazy talk, but if you're willing to talk directly to the Docker API you may be able to get what you want. E.g., using `curl`, we can run pull the `rockylinux:9.1` image like this:

```
curl --unix-socket /run/docker.sock -X POST \
  http://localhost/v1.41/images/create'?fromImage=rockylinux&tag=9.1'
```

This produces as output a series of single-line JSON documents that look something like:

```
{"status":"Pulling from library/rockylinux","id":"9.1"}
{"status":"Pulling fs layer","progressDetail":{},"id":"5d7e16de9e63"}
{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":539961,"total":64393213},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]    540kB/64.39MB","id":"5d7e16de9e63"}
{"status":"Downloading","progressDetail":{"current":3221887,"total":64393213},"progress":"[==\u003e                                                ]  3.222MB/64.39MB","id":"5d7e16de9e63"}
...
{"status":"Verifying Checksum","progressDetail":{},"id":"5d7e16de9e63"}
{"status":"Download complete","progressDetail":{},"id":"5d7e16de9e63"}
{"status":"Extracting","progressDetail":{"current":557056,"total":64393213},"progress":"[\u003e                                                  ]  557.1kB/64.39MB","id":"5d7e16de9e63"}
{"status":"Extracting","progressDetail":{"current":11141120,"total":64393213},"progress":"[========\u003e                                          ]  11.14MB/64.39MB","id":"5d7e16de9e63"}
...
{"status":"Pull complete","progressDetail":{},"id":"5d7e16de9e63"}
{"status":"Digest: sha256:8eb38f164ff94b7e033f6da6c063dabfb7f32f7c179dc7d69cc4ce636cd33355"}
{"status":"Status: Downloaded newer image for rockylinux:9.1"}
```

The `progressDetail` field of the messages with `status == "Downloading"` has exactly what you want.

Obviously doing this with a higher level language (Python/Go/Rust/etc) would be much more convenient.